# RegExp How to link matching beginning/end strings for search/replace?

Tags: regex, capturing-group

I have an XML file and need to find and replace all occurrences of a certain pattern enclosed between either of two pairs of tags, but not mixed between them.

Example

```
 a) <CnlNum>548</CnlNum>
 b) GetBit(Val(548), 3)
```

**548** is the sample text I need to find and change to **1548**. (actually any 3 digit number between 500 and 999 must be replaced by the number+1000).

I used the following:

Search *regex*:

```
(<CnlNum>|Val\s?\()([5-9])(\d{2})(</CnlNum>|\),\s?)
```

Replace *regex*:

```
($1)1$2$3$4
```

The issue is this searching regex, although a working one, doesn't only match corresponding pairs of startin/ending strings, but would also find the following, too, which would be wrong:

```
<CnlNum>548),
```

I wonder how can I link the starting/ending texts in the regex?

I think this would be useful for linking matching XML or HTML tags (<tag>...</tag>).

Comment: Most likely very hard to impossible. Use a XML parser/AST parser instead. What's the programming language?

Comment: Regex can't really do arithmetic.  Pending the reply to the above comment, there might be a programming language with regex way of doing this.

Comment: No language at all. It's a massive search/replace in Notepad++ for 400+ line signals in an industrial SCADA implementation (Notepad++ supports regex).

Comment: Arithmetic is not the issue here. I could manage to do the replacement (not quite adding 1000 to anything, but by writing a '1' before the matching 3 digit number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the alternatives inside the first group and then use a conditional construct:

```php
((<CnlNum>)|(Val\s?\())([5-9])(\d{2})((?(2)</CnlNum>|\),\s?))
 ^        ^ ^        ^                ^^^^^         ^      ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pKyJsT/1). *Details*:

- `((<CnlNum>)|(Val\s?\())` - Group 1: either `<CnlNum>` (Group 2) or `Val` + an optional whitespace and a `(` char (Group 3)
- `([5-9])` - Group 4: a digit from `5` to `9`
- `(\d{2})` - Group 5: any two digits
- `((?(2)</CnlNum>|\),\s?))` - Group 6: if Group 2 matched, match `</CnlNum>` else, match  a `)`, comma, and an optional whitespace.

Comment: Great solution Wiktor! Thanks. This did the job.